# .htaccess Mod Rewrite 'pretty ur'l to actual doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get htaccess to rewrite this url :

```
http://127.0.0.1/papercut3/article/post-title/
```

to this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/papercut3/article.php?p=post-title/
```

My current .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)*$ ./article.php?p=$1  
RewriteRule ^section/(\d+)*$ ./section.php?s=$1
```

And my urls written in the code:

```
http://127.0.0.1/papercut3/article/execution-call-for-cinema-killer/
```

My problem is that when I click the link I get this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /papercut3/article/syria-suffers-deadliest-month/ was not found on this server.
```

I'm using WAMP, the .htaccess is in the root of the /papercut3 directory with all the core files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!:)

Comment: Is module mod_rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: `\d` defines digits not letters.

Comment: @Alasjo - Yes, thanks
@Jon - Do you want to post that as an answer? Changed `\d to .* - Worked perfectly! :)

Comment: @AviateX14 Posted answer per request. ^^ Glad it helped. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `.htaccess` files, you want it to look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ ./article.php?p=$1  
RewriteRule ^section/(.+)$ ./section.php?s=$1
```

Or, you can be slightly more specific with what is allowed, but the one in your question only allows character `[0-9]`, this way it opens it up and let's the respective PHP files do the checking/error-handling.

Answer (score 0):

You may find help in the log file of apache, but I think this is related to [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive, which must be set to None.

As said in the documentation, you need `AllowOverride` to contain at least `FileInfo`.

**Edit**: By the way, your rule won't match any of your url since you expect a int `\d` but don't provide any in input.